# How to checkout git sources on remote machine using local ssh key?

Tags: ssh, git

Machine alice wants to deploy code to machine bob - which is a freshly started server somewhere in the cloud. The code is in private repo alice has ssh keys to.

Basically alice wants to `ssh bob "git clone git@repo"`, but somehow forwarding the keys.

What needs to be done to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called *ssh-agent forwarding* and there is switch `-A` for it in `ssh`. If you are familiar with ssh-agent, just do `ssh -A bob "git clone git@repo"` and it should do the job (possibly try add `-tt` options if it will not work).

If you didn't hear about `ssh-agent`, you can go on reading:

```
eval `ssh-agent`  ## start ssh-agent
ssh-add your.key  ## add your key to agent, possibly unlocking if encrypted
ssh -A bob        ## gets you to remote server with rather safe access to your local key
```